# Install pip3 package locally

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.4

Having used npm for some time, I'm struggling to understand why pip3 (i.e.: pip with Python 3) is so stubborn when it comes to manage permissions.

So far, I've been using pip3 with sudo as I'm the only one using this computer and I don't mind installing packages globally

Today I wanted to install the `pep8` package and use it locally without sudo. pep8 can be used by IDEs and they would not be able to use it without sudo. Therefore, I'd like to run

```
pip3 install --user pep8
```

However, command doesn't work without sudo. Console throws a traceback with a PermissionError:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py'
```

And if run with sudo, quite logically, pep8 is installed in `/root`

With 2.7, the workaround is to uninstall pip and then reinstall it locally with --user. At the moment, though, I'm unable to uninstall pip3. At least in Fedora 22, dependencies seem to be quite tight. My guess is that pip3 comes bundled with 3.4 and that makes matters worse.

And so, running

```
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

gives a permission error because the script looks at current pip3 installations. If I run the command with sudo, the --user works (I believe it's still in testing mode?) but, logically, it installs it in the `/root` folder

In short, is there a way to use pip with Python3 to install packages locally?

Comment: `However, command doesn't work without sudo.` - you may want to be a more specific here.

Comment: `pip3 install --user pep8` works fine for me. Where does pip want to install the `--user` installation for you?

Comment: Just updated my question with the PermissionError I get if I run pip3 without sudo

Comment: "And if run with sudo, quite logically, pep8 is installed in /root". Which it shouldn't: it should install it in `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages` when run with sudo; not in `/root`.

Comment: The "real" permission denied appears to be the fact that the *command* `pip3` can't read `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py`. It's not the installation part, it's the execution part that fails. Somehow, you've managed to install `pip` in a way that the normal user can't read that directory. Check your permissions for the site-packages directory and subdirectories, and change them accordingly. Related question: how did you install `pip3` the first time around?

Comment: Installing in `/root` seems logical in this case because I'm using the "--user" option. As far as I recall, pip came bundled with 3.4, and Python 3.4 came by default with Fedora 22. So I didn't install it either and didn't choose any paths. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#key-terms): "Starting with Python 3.4, it[pip] is included by default with the Python binary installers." I guess I could change permissions for `/site-packages` but it just doesn't feel right

Answer (score 1):

Within a console start your version of python you want to install the package for. 
Run the python with the permission you want it to be installed with.
Python 3 and without `sudo` in this case.

> python3

Thank in the python instance install the package you want.

```
import pip

#Ininstall the package
#This is the path to the setup and unzipped package. Path to the folder with setup.py.
path_to_setup = "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pep8"
#finelly runs the installation
pip.main (['install', path_to_setup])
#You will see some data processed.
#Now test it. In this case the package is pep8
import pep8
```